# Can we do a chi-squared test of independence on nominal(output) and ratio(input) data?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, logistic, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have a data set with `Age` and `Survival Status` column. I have categorized the ages into `Age Group`s namely: `30-47` years old, `48-65` years old and `66-83` years old and have aggregated the `Survival Status` for the ages which fall in the same group. `Survival Status` can have the value as `True` or `False`

I have read many places that the chi-squared test of independence is suitable when we have two nominal variables. I am having `Survival Status` as nominal variable, but `Age` as per my understanding comes under Ratio Data category, which means I have to use chi-squared test for goodness-of-fit.

But goodness of fit doesn't actually answer the question I want to ask from the data. And, intuitively it doesn't feel correct to go for goodness of fit as I want to check the independence/dependence between the different groups.
Moreover, I think that once I have divided the `Age`s in groups, `Age Group` as a whole holds pretty true to fall in the category of Nominal Data.

My question is can I do chi-squared test of independence on such data?

And am I correct when I say that once `age`s has been binned into `age groups`, it can be treated as nominal data?

I am very new to inferential statistics with just 2 months of learning. So please correct me if I am wrong in any of the above statements.

The question I am finding answer to is:

> Does the treatment affects different age groups differently?

So I actually want to test whether the survival status is independent of age groups or not.

`True` means: the patient survived 5 years or longer post treatment.

`False` means: the patient died within 5 year post treatment.

Dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Haberman%27s+Survival

Comment: What does it mean for you for age to be independent of survival status? Ie, what is it you really ultimately want to know and why? Also, if survival status is `dead` vs `not dead yet`, it is more of an event / censoring indicator than a true nominal variable.

Comment: The question I am finding answer to is: "Does the treatment affects different age groups differently?" So I actually want to test whether the survival status is independent of age groups or not.
`True` means:  the patient survived 5 years or longer post treatment.
`False` means: the patient died within 5 year post treatment.

Comment: What is age then? Do you want to compare these proportions between ages? Do you have access to the true ages, or do you only have binned ages because that's how they were recorded (eg, for privacy reasons)?

Comment: I have access to true ages, I binned them myself to ease my process as I won't be using any software to perform the test.

Comment: You should use software to do this. It is possible to perform the calculations by hand, but it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: I cannot use software, as this is a project submission for Udacity Course and I need to do it manually.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Did they tell you to use a chi-squared test?

Comment: I have to decide which test to run out of all the tests, I have been taught in the course which includes z-tests, t-tests, analysis of variance, regression and chi-squared tests.
And my understanding is that out of the above mentioned tests, only chi-squared test fit for the question being asked as it involves `Survival Status` as a response variable which is a categorical data. Correct me if I am mistaken?

Comment: I wouldn't have designed the study like this, & if I had these data, I would use logistic regression. But introductory courses always have goofy examples, because students don't really know enough to handle the kind of complexity that happens in the real world. Within the tests listed, the chi-squared is the only real option.

Comment: So if you're going to go w/ the chi-squared test, there are different versions. You don't have to use the chi-squared test for goodness of fit. Have you covered any other versions of the chi-squared test?

Comment: Yes, goodness of fit doesn't really fits the question. The course covered two versions: goodness of fit and test of independence.
I am good to go with test of independence. The only doubt I have is I do not actually have two nominal variables and the course as well as external links I have researched on says I need to have at least two nominal response variables to go for test of independence.

Comment: On the other hand, it feels like, once I have converted the individual `age`s into age bins, I have actually made them categorical anyway, so I should be able to continue with test for independence. Not sure whether this explanation is correct?

Comment: Yes, as I say, I wouldn't use the chi-squared test here; I'd use logistic regression. But out of the tests you've learned, the chi-squared is the one to try. Can you turn the age variable into a nominal variable?

Comment: Talking about the regression, after seeing the dataset for the first time, the very first test that came to my mind was regression only, where `age`, `number of positive axillary nodes` and may be `year of operation` too could have been predictor variables, and `Survival Status` could be the outcome. But then I realized that 'Survival Status' is categorical so couldn't continue.

Just now saw Wikipedia that logistic regression as mentioned by you actually solves this exact problem. Will see if I can learn that first and then continue with the same.

Comment: If they are expecting you to do this by hand then I would have thought logistic regression was a challenge too far. I agree with @gung that chi-square is probably your best bet of the ones you know.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks. Will read about logistic regression first and then will see what to go with. And by manually I meant Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi @gung
I did this as project: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLTxtzmr2lL2DZbYCNN3SOrq32Kvs1yG5MDb5RsWkL0/edit?usp=sharing)

Any feedbacks?

Comment: @mdewey

Any feedbacks for this:
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLTxtzmr2lL2DZbYCNN3SOrq32Kvs1yG5MDb5RsWkL0/edit?usp=sharing) ?